# Start a gRpc server from it's client

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I worked through the .net core sample application for a grpc client and server. If the server is not running the client tosses an exception trying to connect to it. Okay.

Can the client catch this exception and then start the server, if they both exist on the same pc? I'm doing this with tcpchannels in a .net framework app. Because we want many local clients to share one server, but we don't want it running before the client starts, this is a requirement.

Thanks,

Comment: If the server is a different executable on the same machine, you could use the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to start the server application after catching the exception, wait a few seconds, and retry.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Right now I don't think I'll be using gRPC.